# Confluence naming rules for folders created through WebDAV

Tags: confluence

When I try to create folders in Confluence using WebDAV, I frequently run into issues.

For example, these directory names don't seem to be allowed:

- `css`
- `images`

Code example:

```
chris@localhost /cygdrive/w/Personal/~chris/Home
$ mkdir css
mkdir: cannot create directory `css': Permission denied

chris@localhost /cygdrive/w/Personal/~chris/Home
$ mkdir cssfolder  # This works ok!
```

Also, it seems that Confluence does not like a child folder if it has the same name as a grandparent's folder name.

Is there is list of the rules that define what is and isn't allowed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have a reference page for reserved names, but one thing to know is that you can’t create 2 pages with the same name in a Confluence space, which may translate (for WebDAV) as: below `~chris` you cannot, even very deep, create 2 folders with the same name.

Answer (score 0):

you tried this

```
mkdir /cygdrive/w/Personal/~chris/Home/css
```

or this

```
mkdir -p css/anything
```

is there a css directory already?

```
find . -type d
```

it´s wicked because cssfolder works :-\